# Count number of faces using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tracking.js

Is there a way that I can count the number of faces in a live camera.

For example I've three persons in front of a webcam and I'm having 2 pages say, **Success.html** and **error .html** and as part of the underlying way to judge the redirection to *Success* or *error* pages the condition would be, if only one face is detected, it should be sent to *success*, else, it should be sent to *error* .

I'm using **tracking.js** to detect the face in my web page and currently my code is as below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>tracking.js - face with camera</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/demo.css">

<script src="js/tracking-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/face-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/stats.min.js"></script>

<style>
video, canvas {
    margin-left: 230px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="demo-title">
        <p>
            <a href="http://trackingjs.com" target="_parent">tracking.js</a> －
            get user's webcam and detect faces
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="demo-frame">
        <div class="demo-container">
            <video id="video" width="320" height="240" preload autoplay loop
                muted></video>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');
            tracker.setInitialScale(4);
            tracker.setStepSize(2);
            tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

            tracking.track('#video', tracker, {
                camera : true
            });

            tracker.on('track', function(event) {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                event.data
                        .forEach(function(rect) {

                    console.log('face detected');
                });
            });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here in my console I'm able to print, `face detected`.

please let me know how can I detect multiples faces in this window.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the tracking.js documentation? It looks quite complete.

Comment: event.data.length?

Comment: So 2 or more faces should cause redirect to `error.html` right? Do you know redirect because counting the detected faces is just a manner of checking `event.data.length` (0 for no faces, 1 for 1 face etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
myTracker.on('track', function(event) {
  if (event.data.length === 0) {
    // No targets were detected in this frame.
  } else {
    event.data.forEach(function(data) {
      // Plots the detected targets here.
    });
  }
});
```

It seems to be `event.data.length` that gives you the number of tracked elements.

Answer (score 1):

Fom the docs at https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#trackers

> ```
> myTracker.on('track', function(event) {
>   if (event.data.length === 0) {
>     // No targets were detected in this frame.
>   } else {
>     event.data.forEach(function(data) {
>       // Plots the detected targets here.
>     });
>   }
> });
> ```

Use `event.data.length` to count the amount of faces.

On your piece of code :

```
tracker.on('track', function(event) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // console log amount of elements found
    console.log(event.data.length);
    event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
        console.log('face detected');
    });
});
```