# Stop a function after getting one image

Tags: javascript

This is an extension to my previous question available at [Count number of faces using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669982/count-number-of-faces-using-javascript?noredirect=1#comment76324766_44669982). Here my requirement is once an image with one face is detected, the process should be stopped, but in my case it is a never ending loop.

> 1  is the length
>
> 1 face detected

I tried the below codes.

```
    tracker.on('track', function(event) {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                console.log(event.data.length + "\t is the length");
                if (event.data.length == 1) {
                    console.log('1 faces detected');
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log('Multiple faces detected');
                }    
            });
```

The above code doesn't have any impact on the output(The loop never ends).

But instead I used a `break` as follows.

```
tracker.on('track', function(event) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            console.log(event.data.length + "\t is the length");
            if (event.data.length == 1) {
                console.log('1 face detected');
                break;
            } else {
                console.log('Multiple faces detected');
            }
        });
```

But the above code gives me an exception as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`, I know that break is supposed to be used only for `loops` or `if`, thought that in my current scenario, it is looping, I used it.

Here is my code.

```
   window.onload = function() {
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');
            tracker.setInitialScale(4);
            tracker.setStepSize(2);
            tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

            tracking.track('#video', tracker, {
                camera : true
            });

            tracker.on('track', function(event) {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                console.log(event.data.length + "\t is the length");
                if (event.data.length == 1) {
                    console.log('1 face detected');
                    tracking.track('#video', tracker).stop();
                } else {
                    console.log('Multiple faces detected');
                }
                
            });
        };
```

Going through the documentation I saw that there is a `stop()` method, I used it, but still it doesn't stop. Can someone please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I stop further looping after getting 1 image.

I'm using the same `trackingjs.js` and the method I found is available at https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#trackers

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `removeListener` from `tracker`.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');
    tracker.setInitialScale(4);
    tracker.setStepSize(2);
    tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

    tracking.track('#video', tracker, {
        camera : true
    });
    function trackListener(event) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log(event.data.length + "\t is the length");
        if (event.data.length == 1) {
            console.log('1 face detected');
            tracker.removeListener('track', trackListener);
        } else {
            console.log('Multiple faces detected');
        }

    }
    tracker.on('track', trackListener);
};
```

or use `once` method

```
tracker.once('track', trackListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop listening to tracking events after the first track for a single face. I think this can work:

```
if (event.data.length == 1) {
    console.log('1 face detected');
    tracking.stop(); //Not tracker, tracking
}
```

Or this: **EDITTED**

```
if (event.data.length == 1) {
    console.log('1 face detected');
    tracker.on('track', function(event){});
}
```

Comment: This is giving the error as `Uncaught TypeError: Listener must be a function` on `tracker.on('track', {});` and `Uncaught TypeError: tracker.stop is not a function` when I use `tracker.stop();`